Laravel UUID instead of regular bigInteger in models trims uuid
I'm trying to work with uuid instead of regular integer id.
Migration
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique()->index();

            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->text('description');
           

        });

I create a record in the database, read it and try to access the id property
  dd (Product::first());

  "id" => "3246c4a7-9757-11e8-80d0-00155dbf5a2a"
  "name" => "tea"
  "description" => "dummy description"

The results are correct, but if I try to access the property Product::first()->id directly, I get a truncated UUD.
3246 // app/Http/Controllers/Web/ProductsController.php:21
The same situation if I convert to an array or a json Product::first()->toArray()
array:3 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Web/ProductsController.php:21
  "id" => 3246
  "name" => "tea"
  "description" => "dummy description"

Why does Laravel 11.33.2 truncate the uuid when accessing through object properties?

Does your model use the use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids; trait? I can partially recreate this via Model::first()->uuid returning the correct, full UUID "9c794818-994a-4e25-8c6a-2efcbe67f2c0" with that trait, but only returning "9" without that trait.

@TimLewis Thanks for your help. Found the problem, it is necessary to add a property to the model that works with UUID protected $keyType = 'string'; by default there int

Interesting, I guess that works? The HasUuids trait does something similar: if (in_array($this->getKeyName(), $this->uniqueIds())) { return 'string'; }. Any reason you're not using this Trait?

@TimLewis For some reason this trait doesn't work for me use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;

Hmm... I wonder why. Unfortunately I don't have a Laravel 11 project to verify this. If this approach works for you that's totally fine too, I was just curious what approach you were taking, since in my experience, using uuids requires the additional logic contained in that Trait

  //Need to add a property to the model


   class Product extends Model {
         
        protected $keyType = 'string';
        
   }


class Product extends Model
{
    use HasUuids;
}

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique()->index();
    $table->string('name', 100);
    $table->text('description');
});


class Product extends Model
{
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;

}
